# Windows Forms - RaiseEvent from a Parent Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, logging

I have a Windows Forms project I'm fixing now in VB.NET.

I need to call `RaiseEvent` on an event of the parent form in order to route logging to an application calling the parent form.

Similar to this:
[RaiseEvent from a UserControl that's placed on a UserControl that's on a Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656965/raiseevent-from-a-usercontrol-thats-placed-on-a-usercontrol-thats-on-a-form)

But opposite. I need to push an event one level down, rather than bubble it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One object cannot raise events that belong to other object.

You should create a Sub in the parent to raise this event for you.

[Parent]

```
(...)
Friend Sub RaiseMyEvent() 
    RaiseEvent MyEvent(Me,EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
(...)
```

[Child]

```
(...)
parentObject.RaiseMyEvent()
(...)
```