# in vb.net how do I raise an event of another control

Tags: vb.net, events

Every sample I've seen that refers to this is about mouse clicks and then the example is the same.

I need to specifically raise an event on another control.

I have a panel with an event that I created like this:

```
Private FlowPanel as new my_FlowLayoutPanel
Addhandler FlowPanel.change, addressof doChange

    Public Class my_FlowLayoutPanel
            Inherits FlowLayoutPanel

            Public Event change(ByVal sender As Object)
            Public Const Ver_SCROLL As Integer = &H115

            Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
                If m.Msg = Ver_SCROLL Then
                    RaiseEvent change(Me)
                End If

                MyBase.WndProc(m)
            End Sub
        End Class
```

So when the vertical scroll bar moves, the "change" event fires.

So now, I have another control, (a simple panel) set up like this:

```
Public Class view_Panel
        Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Panel

        Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)

            Const NCMOUSEMOVE As Integer = &H200

            If m.Msg = NCMOUSEMOVE Then

              ' *** FIRE THE "CHANGE" EVENT ON THE FLOWLAYOUT PANEL

            End If
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
        End Sub

    End Class
```

So, how do I fire the "Change" event from the view_Panel?

Comment: How do these controls relate to each other on a form?

Comment: Where does my_FlowLayoutPanel reside?

Answer (score 2):

Even after reading other answers such as 'Pouya Samie' above (reflect to `OnChange` if available), or this more enhanced article "[Raising Events Using Reflection](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ReflectionRaiseEvents.aspx)" which seems much cleaner but doesn't always work (reflect to `MulticastDelegate`)...

So finally got to put all my ideas in order for a **generic method** to perform this task with a **simple syntax**:

```
TriggerEvent(ComboBox1, "OnSelectedIndexChanged")
```

Notice that the above method is **private non-accesible** inside the ComboBox1, it is even **NOT listed** on the IntelliSense list members, but with this reflection method it will work OK:

```
''' <summary>
''' Manually trigger an existing event in a control.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="ctrlObject">The GUI control that that should be operated (such as ComboBox).</param>
''' <param name="onEventName">The OnEvent function regardless of the scope (such as OnSelectedIndexChanged).</param>
''' <returns><code>True</code> when the method is found invoked and returned successfully; <code>false</code> otherwise.</returns>
Public Function TriggerEvent(ctrlObject As Control, onEventName As String) As Boolean

    ' Get the reference to the method
    Dim methodRef As MethodInfo = ctrlObject.GetType().GetMethod(onEventName, _
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Static Or _
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
    If IsNothing(methodRef) Then Return False

    ' Invoke the method
    Try
        methodRef.Invoke(ctrlObject, New Object() {EventArgs.Empty})
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** 
To Call your Event From Another Class you can use reflection

```
 MethodInfo onchange = YourClassInstance.GetType().GetMethod("OnChange",              System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    onChange.Invoke(YourClassInstance, new object[] { new EventArgs() });
```

Comment: While a good article, it mentions nothing of raising events of other controls.

Comment: Look at Steps 2 And 3 In my Update Answer

Comment: You just reproduced the article by copying it here. After copying it, nothing has changed. So my question remains: What code would you insert into my program where it says "' *** FIRE THE "CHANGE" EVENT ON THE FLOWLAYOUT PANEL"?

Comment: To raise an event from outside the declaring class you will have to derive the class and add a public wrapper method

Comment: Step 2 creates a class called Sender and an event called Start, then Step 3 just triggers the Start event in same class. If I use the same logic for my code, then I would put "RaiseEvent change()" in place of my code and I get the error: 'change' is not an event of view_Panel.

Comment: Sorry I thought you have problem in your class :
As you know you can inherit your class from base but coz you can not have multiple Inheritance you should use reflection Look at my Edit

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
Case WM_HSCROLL
     RaiseEvent Scroll(Me, New ScrollEventArgs(ScrollEventType.EndScroll, _
           Win32.GetScrollPos(Me.Handle, Win32.SBOrientation.SB_HORZ), _ 
           ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll))

Case WM_VSCROLL
     RaiseEvent Scroll(Me, New ScrollEventArgs(ScrollEventType.EndScroll, _
           Win32.GetScrollPos(Me.Handle, Win32.SBOrientation.SB_VERT), _
           ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll))
```

`ScrollEventArgs` is a standard Net event, so we dont need to define it.  Then declare the event as ('change' seems a very poor choice):

```
Public Event Scroll(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal sa As ScrollEventArgs)
```

If your Panel needs to do something with the event, use the OnScroll method, which allows the panel to do stuff before the end subscriber gets the event:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnScroll(ByVal sa As ScrollEventArgs)
    ... do stuff
    ' in cases where you no longer need the event to be passed
    ' on, dont call this:
    MyBase.OnScroll(e)
End Sub
```

**How to use:**

Since you subclass both, let the Panel raise the event, the FlowPanel can monitor those events (subscribe to the panel's scroll event) and in that, do whatever you were going to do in `Change`.  Since the ACTION takes place in/on the panel, better to just handle it there.